# OCaml. about if statement

Tags: if-statement, boolean, ocaml

I have a mistake in my code. How to use functions, which return bool in if statement?

```
let pol a b c = 
    let p=(a+.b+.c)/.2.0 in sqrt(p*.(p-.a)*.(p-.b)*.(p-.c));;

let test a b c = 
    (a+.b)>c &&(b+.c)>a &&(a+.c)>b

let main a b c = 
    let w=test(a b c) in(
    if w
     then pol (a b c)
     else raise(Failure "Error"));;
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see your problems are in your calls to `pol` and `test`. You've defined both of these functions so that they take three separate arguments, but you're passing them both a single argument representing a strange function call.

An idiomatic function call in OCaml does not have parentheses:

```
# let f a b = a + b;;
val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# f 3 8;;
- : int = 11
```

You're trying to do something more like this:

```
# f (3 8);;
Error: This expression has type int
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

As you can see, if you write `(3 8)` you're asking to treat `3` as a function that should be passed `8` as an argument. There's an analogous problem with `(a b c)` in your code.